# How to export Godot scene for web HTML?

Tags: html, webgl, webgl2, godot

How do I export Godot scene for web HTML?

I use Godot Engine v3.0.6. I have downloaded appropriate template and successfully exported scene, but when i try to browse it I receive error: WebGL 2 not available. How do i fix this? Is it possible to export scene with earlier version of WebGL, so it can run on most browsers and devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WebGL 2 is simply a requirement of the code the Godot Engine HTML5 export generates, as stated right at the start of the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_web.html). This is not something you can "fix".

Personally, I feel it's a bit early to use this technology for any mainstream projects, but that's very much a matter of opinion. As an alternative, Unity offers a similar WebAssembly-based pipeline, which has matured a bit more and offers WebGL. Or you could use *actual web-based technology* to develop for the web in stead of cross-compiling, which might or might not make sense given your project requirements.